# Pandas making cumulative Z scores map onto dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

I have a Pandas Dataframe full of sports scores and stats containing multiple leagues and seasons.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Season' : ['2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011'],
              'League' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
              'Date' : [datetime.date(2010, 8, 9), datetime.date(2010, 8, 9), datetime.date(2010, 8, 15), datetime.date(2010, 8, 15), datetime.date(2011, 8, 13), 
                        datetime.date(2011, 8, 14), datetime.date(2011, 9, 1), datetime.date(2011, 9, 1), datetime.date(2011, 9, 4), datetime.date(2011, 9, 7)],
              'Team' : ['Bulls', 'Bunnies', 'Bears', 'Bunnies', 'Bulls', 'Dogs', 'Bears', 'Dogs', 'Bears', 'Bunnies'],
              'Score' : [75, 95, 65, 81, 83, 77, 67, 49, 82, 68]})
```

I would like to map a Z score onto the Dataframe for a particular stat for each team.  With the Z score tracking how a team is doing compared to the rest of the teams within its league.

This function does what I want and returns a dictionary but I don't know how to map the dictionary on to the dataframe, or if it is the best way of going about it.

```
import scipy.stats as ss 
def makeCumZScoreMap(ratingType, frame, lg, season, dateObj):     
    zScoreDict =  {}    
    sampleFrame = frame[(frame.League == lg) & (frame.Season == season) & (frame.Date <= dateObj)]
    rating = sampleFrame.groupby(['Team'])[ratingType].mean()          
    for x, y in dict(pd.Series(ss.zscore(rating, ddof=1), rating.index)).iteritems():     
        zScoreDict[x] =  y                
    return zScoreDict
```

This returns a dictionary with the Z score for dataframe column 'Score' for league 'A' in season '2010' for games on or before '2010-08-09'.

```
makeCumZScoreMap('Score', df, 'A', '2010', datetime.date(2010, 8, 9))
```

This would be an example of  the desired output:

```
             Date League  Score Season     Team  Zscore
     0  2010-08-09      A     75   2010    Bulls    0.70
     1  2010-08-09      A     95   2010  Bunnies   -0.70
     2  2010-08-15      B     65   2010    Bears    nan
     3  2010-08-15      A     81   2010  Bunnies    etc.
     4  2011-08-13      B     83   2011    Bulls
     5  2011-08-14      A     77   2011     Dogs
     6  2011-09-01      A     67   2011    Bears
     7  2011-09-01      A     49   2011     Dogs
     8  2011-09-04      B     82   2011    Bears
     9  2011-09-07      B     68   2011  Bunnies
```

Comment: how do you call your function ? (what is `ratingType`, etc..)

Comment: ratingType is the column that I want to compute the Z score for in the example it would be 'Score'

Comment: but can you just show an example of how you call it (ie edit your question)? and what is `ss` refering to?

Comment: ok ss is scipy.stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map` to map a dictionary to values contained within a pandas dataframe.

```
import scipy.stats as ss 
def makeCumZScoreMap(ratingType, frame, lg, season, dateObj):     
    zScoreDict =  {}    
    sampleFrame = frame[(frame.League == lg) & (frame.Season == season) & (frame.Date <= dateObj)]
    rating = sampleFrame.groupby(['Team'])[ratingType].mean()          
    for x, y in dict(pd.Series(ss.zscore(rating, ddof=1), rating.index)).iteritems():     
        zScoreDict[x] =  y                
    frame['Zscore'] = frame['Team'].map(zScoreDict)
    return frame
```

This will modify the dataframe that you pass into it. You can can create a copy within the function, and modify that, then pass the modified dataframe as the return value if you don't want to modify the original.